# Extracting individual columns of data in R

Tags: r

I have a simulation algorithm that I studied to compare the performance of multiple estimators for a two-parameter distribution, where `tout` is the object of the simulation and the results for the first 6 iterations are given as:

```
head(tout)
[[1]]
     MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1     WLSE2      CVM1 
0.5386432 0.4382962 0.5099481 0.4715912 0.5117606 0.4602767 0.4651867 0.4988287 0.5257753 
     CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2 
0.4541418 0.5647531 0.4279015 0.5084405 0.4425654 

[[2]]
     MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1     WLSE2      CVM1 
0.6440018 0.3967015 0.5765640 0.4677472 0.6514293 0.3987146 0.5970640 0.4396663 0.6687088 
     CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2 
0.3915725 0.6977988 0.3744663 0.6168053 0.4001208 

[[3]]
     MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1     WLSE2      CVM1 
0.7026951 0.4104054 0.5068797 0.5920761 0.7095411 0.4512077 0.5186618 0.5788831 0.7413820 
     CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2 
0.4389810 0.9342899 0.3370598 0.6385650 0.4243651 

[[4]]
     MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1     WLSE2      CVM1 
0.5978735 0.5018492 0.5209601 0.5734814 0.6299665 0.4931704 0.5557625 0.5426690 0.6490281 
     CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2 
0.4872303 0.6688643 0.4783249 0.5608085 0.5056437 

[[5]]
     MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1     WLSE2      CVM1 
0.6342671 0.3089608 0.5868977 0.3669342 0.6292674 0.3223752 0.5960829 0.3499934 0.6436543 
     CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2 
0.3149113 0.6847822 0.2869070 0.6003836 0.3170046 

[[6]]
     MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1     WLSE2      CVM1 
0.6470335 0.3835832 0.6044660 0.4289784 0.6264162 0.4015191 0.5790582 0.4369397 0.6436909 
     CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2 
0.3942025 0.6852247 0.3690787 0.6126173 0.3894142
```

I would like to extract all values for MLE1, MLE2, and so on. I tried using `tout[1,]`, but it did not work. The error message it gave was `Error in tout[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`. How do I extract all values separately for MLE1, MLE2, and so on?

Comment: Would a valid answer to your question be different if the source of the data was not simulation, or did not involve estimates? It looks to me like the answer is no, you're asking a purely R syntax question and spamming the `simulation` and `estimation` tags. If picking off particular columns is related to estimation, or is done differently because of simulation, that needs some explanation.

Comment: Well, the data is a result of simulation which investigates the performance of several estimators. I don't think I am spamming those tags, just selecting keywords related to my questions.

Comment: Would the work required to pick off a subset of columns be any different if the data were read in from a file? Do you have issues with the simulation itself? If the answer to these questions is no, then you're spamming groups with tags that don't apply to your actual question. If the answer is yes, then you need to explain why and supply suitable code so that your problem is reproducible and how simulation is potential source of issues. I came to your question because I'm a simulation person. I see nothing in your question other than the brief mention that your data comes from a simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` with `[`:

```r
l <- replicate(3, c(MLE1 = 0.641151978310245,  MLE2 = 0.343605418474544, MOME1 = 0.589030092164895, MOME2 = 0.402978104488642, OLSE1 = 0.592058622388682, OLSE2 = 0.391744158767641, WLSE1 = 0.555834606688624, WLSE2 = 0.421744980944362, CVM1 = 0.607818252992196, CVM2 = 0.384273611960049, MCVM1 = 0.698076643246126, MCVM2 = 0.323239571664426, MPS1 = 0.615145435338788, MPS2 = 0.347714221623107),
          simplify = F)
 #mock data set

t(sapply(l, `[`, seq(length(l[[1]]))))

#          MLE1      MLE2     MOME1     MOME2     OLSE1     OLSE2     WLSE1
# [1,] 0.641152 0.3436054 0.5890301 0.4029781 0.5920586 0.3917442 0.5558346
# [2,] 0.641152 0.3436054 0.5890301 0.4029781 0.5920586 0.3917442 0.5558346
# [3,] 0.641152 0.3436054 0.5890301 0.4029781 0.5920586 0.3917442 0.5558346
#         WLSE2      CVM1      CVM2     MCVM1     MCVM2      MPS1      MPS2
# [1,] 0.421745 0.6078183 0.3842736 0.6980766 0.3232396 0.6151454 0.3477142
# [2,] 0.421745 0.6078183 0.3842736 0.6980766 0.3232396 0.6151454 0.3477142
# [3,] 0.421745 0.6078183 0.3842736 0.6980766 0.3232396 0.6151454 0.3477142
```

Comment: I couldn't run your second command. It says something about unexpected ">" and dim(x).

Comment: Check your R version, it might be because of that. If too early, do `sapply(l, `[`, 1:2)`

Comment: ```sapply(l, '[', 1:2)``` worked. Thanks.

Comment: Check the short form in the answer

Comment: It only worked for the example you gave. It didn't for mine. Once I used ```sapply(l, '[', 1:2)```, the format of the ```l``` changed and it became easier to extract after all. But mine stays the same as in original question. I used ```sapply(l, '[', 1:14)``` because there are 14 columns of data.

Comment: You should share your data set in the question (use dput). I cannot really help you if I don't have access to it

Comment: The results from ```dput()``` is very long but the last entry was like this: ```c(MLE1 = 0.641151978310245, 
MLE2 = 0.343605418474544, MOME1 = 0.589030092164895, MOME2 = 0.402978104488642, OLSE1 = 0.592058622388682, OLSE2 = 0.391744158767641, WLSE1 = 0.555834606688624, WLSE2 = 0.421744980944362, CVM1 = 0.607818252992196, CVM2 = 0.384273611960049, MCVM1 = 0.698076643246126, MCVM2 = 0.323239571664426, MPS1 = 0.615145435338788, MPS2 = 0.347714221623107))```. It was similar for each 1000 simulation. It was basically a list type with ```c(),c(),...,c()```.

Comment: It really depends on what is your expected output. See edit

Comment: I think the problem may be how the simulated results are presented. ```is.numeric(tout)``` gives ```FALSE```. I think that may be the problem that I need to rectify first.

Comment: I found that when the replication is smaller, the data is easier to extract. So, I probably will have to run 100 iterations 10 times or 200 iterations 5 times to get to 1000 iterations.